# How to start on specific cell in a loop using apache poi?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I have an app that reads an excel and gets the information. This is my code that reads the information from column 0 and column 1. I want to know a way to start only on row number 34 and skip row 1 from 33.

```
File file = new File(inFileName);
            Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0);


            Iterator<Row> rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
            while(rowIter.hasNext()){

                Row myRow =rowIter.next();


                Cell cell1 = myRow.getCell(0);
                Cell cell2 = myRow.getCell(1);
                ...


                Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    Cell myCell = cellIter.next();

                }

                //bd.addAnimalls(cell1.toString(),cell2.toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on inserting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get specific rows using `sheet.getRow(rowNum)`.

So your code can be changed to this:

```
File file = new File(inFileName);
Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

int rowCtr = 33;
Row myRow = sheet.getRow(rowCtr++);
while (myRow != null) {
    Cell cell1 = myRow.getCell(0);
    // rest of your loop code

    myRow = sheet.getRow(rowCtr++);
}
```

Comment: I put that inside while(rowIter.hasNext)?

Comment: This is to replace your loop. I will edit to give you a better idea.

Comment: Thank you so much :) can you please upvote my question too? :)